# I can't delete property of result from mongoosejs findone

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I want result to be sent without password. Then I do:

```
Delete req.session.user.password
res.send(req.session.user)
```

Password still remains there. Why?
How can I delete a property that I don't want to response back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your mongoose user model object into a plain JavaScript object before deleting the password.

```
var user = req.session.user.toObject();
delete user.password;
res.send(user);
```